# log4j:ERROR Error occured while converting date

Tags: java, log4j

I found this exception in my logs:

> log4j:ERROR Error occured while converting date.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.getChars(AbstractStringBuilder.java:328)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.getChars(StringBuffer.java:201)
>       at org.apache.log4j.helpers.ISO8601DateFormat.format(ISO8601DateFormat.java:130)
>       at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:316)
>       at org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternParser$DatePatternConverter.convert(PatternParser.java:443)
>       at org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternConverter.format(PatternConverter.java:65)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.format(PatternLayout.java:506)
>       at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:310)
>       at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
>       at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
>       at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
>       at org.obliquid.db.ConnectionManager.releaseConnection(ConnectionManager.java:313)
>       at org.obliquid.db.ConnectionManager.finalize(ConnectionManager.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:83)
>       at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:14)
>       at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:160)

I think it could be caused by my log4j.properties file, in particular by ConversionPattern. Any idea on how to fix?

```
#Updated at Wed Sep 14 21:57:51 CEST 2011
#Wed Sep 14 21:57:51 CEST 2011
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.R.File=yamweb.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.logger.yamweb=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=WARN
```

**UPDATE**: Actually, looking at the [PatternLayout JavaDoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html), I don't even mention a date format.

**d** Used to output the date of the logging event. The date conversion specifier may be followed by a date format specifier enclosed between braces. For example, %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} or %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}. If no date format specifier is given then ISO8601 format is assumed.

I've added an explicit conversion pattern: `%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %p %c - %m%n`-- looking at the log and I will let you know if it helps.

**UPDATE 2**: the problem didn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 4):

It seems this is a very rare situation. Googling for the error turned up the following discussion from 2006, something to do with class un-loading:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.log4j.user/13835

> I did look at the code in question.  If lastTimeString was somehow
>   not initialized on class reload, then there could be a NPE on the
>   call to getChars().  However, short of a some failure in the VM or a
>   class reloading hack, I don't see how lastTimeString could be null.

EDIT: See question above for a solution:

> I've added an explicit conversion pattern: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %p %c - %m%n

This also seemed to work for the following question: [NPE with Perf4j and Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518392/npe-with-perf4j-and-log4j).

Comment: Thanks, the stack trace is in fact quite similar, I'm not sure if the cause of it is the same though. Changing the date format solved the problem, I've edited my question to confirm that the problem was solved.

Comment: http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com/2010/08/error-occured-while-converting-date.html seems to agree

Comment: Solved the exact problem for me :)

Comment: The [docs state](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) that "dedicated date formatters perform significantly better than SimpleDateFormat" so be aware it may change the apps performace characteristics

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled upon this exception, and it was solved by removing `log4j.jar` from the portlet (or servlet, whatever) folder.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but I fixed this problem by restarting the server.  Yeah, cliche answer, but worth a try